how to modify/concatenate a column's string entry with a string entries from another dataframe's column?
i would like to concatenate the string value of one column's entries with those from another dataframe's column entries where the numbered index ids of the entries match, but the column length does not. ( df1 has 1000 entries, df2 has 100 entries)
this is what i have for code:
df1\["File-Name:"\] = df1\["File-Name:"\].str.cat(df2\["File-Name:"\])

i would like to understand why i am having issues with the syntax.
my result should leave the 900 entries left in the original state but modify the 100 entries where i add string to the orignal 100 specified entries. the entries in both df share index number for their rows.
my approach resulted with the 900 entries that were supposed to be left unchanged but were resulted in Nan values. here row 14 is correct as are the 100 other correctly concatenated entries.
> File-Name:    date-time:  Size:
> 0 NaN 2024-04-26 18:07    830172
> 1 NaN 2024-03-29 19:09    506588
> 2 NaN 2024-04-26 16:14    469096
> 3 NaN 2024-04-18 17:31    437680
> 4 NaN 2024-04-18 17:31    437676
> 5 NaN 2024-04-18 17:31    437672
> 6 NaN 2024-03-29 19:09    430596
> 7 NaN 2024-03-29 19:09    430592
> 8 NaN 2024-04-17 13:01    377076
> 9 NaN 2024-04-26 16:07    362192
> 10    NaN 2024-04-26 16:07    238260
> 11    NaN 2024-03-06 19:11    171496
> 12    NaN 2024-03-06 19:24    167192
> 13    NaN 2024-03-06 19:27    166940
> 14    ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64/7e2ea6e5edddeede43c966070975591a581c4ae0792a9b1a8af685de0311e77fec00f3ce2303de1affbe390e7b22b96402f66e9354a817ac84e6e0cd7eb74bd1    2024-03-06 19:27    166936

df1 looks like this:
File-Name:  date-time:  Size:
0   ./.c9   2024-04-26 18:07    830172
1   ./.nvm  2024-03-29 19:09    506588
2   ./.local    2024-04-26 16:14    469096
3   ./.local/lib    2024-04-18 17:31    437680
4   ./.local/lib/python3.10 2024-04-18 17:31    437676
5   ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages   2024-04-18 17:31    437672
6   ./.nvm/versions 2024-03-29 19:09    430596
7   ./.nvm/versions/node    2024-03-29 19:09    430592
8   ./.c9/dependencies  2024-04-17 13:01    377076
9   ./.cache    2024-04-26 16:07    362192
10  ./.cache/pip    2024-04-26 16:07    238260
11  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1   2024-03-06 19:11    171496
12  ./.c9/node  2024-03-06 19:24    167192
13  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64 2024-03-06 19:27    166940
14  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64/7e2ea6e5edddeede43c966070975591a581c4ae0792a9b1a8af6    2024-03-06 19:27    166936
16  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.0   2024-03-29 19:09    153080


df2 looks like this:


     File-Name:
 14  85de0311e77fec00f3ce2303de1affbe390e7b22b96402f66e9354a817ac84e6e0cd7eb74bd1
 18   e04e9ef74933c4cab24ec0f62a973d0b06e59e466286a73382db011071887b5eafad4b8b9
 20   e04e9ef74933c4cab24ec0f62a973d0b06e59e466286a73382db011071887b5eafad4b8b9/package
 33   85de0311e77fec00f3ce2303de1affbe390e7b22b96402f66e9354a817ac84e6e0cd7eb74bd1/bin


the correct outcome ought look like this:
File-Name:  date-time:  Size:
0   ./.c9   2024-04-26 18:07    830172
1   ./.nvm  2024-03-29 19:09    506588
2   ./.local    2024-04-26 16:14    469096
3   ./.local/lib    2024-04-18 17:31    437680
4   ./.local/lib/python3.10 2024-04-18 17:31    437676
5   ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages   2024-04-18 17:31    437672
6   ./.nvm/versions 2024-03-29 19:09    430596
7   ./.nvm/versions/node    2024-03-29 19:09    430592
8   ./.c9/dependencies  2024-04-17 13:01    377076
9   ./.cache    2024-04-26 16:07    362192
10  ./.cache/pip    2024-04-26 16:07    238260
11  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1   2024-03-06 19:11    171496
12  ./.c9/node  2024-03-06 19:24    167192
13  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64 2024-03-06 19:27    166940
14  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64/7e2ea6e5edddeede43c966070975591a581c4ae0792a9b1a8af685de0311e77fec00f3ce2303de1affbe390e7b22b96402f66e9354a817ac84e6e0cd7eb74bd1    2024-03-06 19:27    166936
15  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.0   2024-03-29 19:09    153080


first use pandas join to join df1 and df2 on index and then concatenate the strings

Pls explain better your expectation. Better to post sample data of the two dataframe and the resulting dataframe

any answers? i can't find any answers anywhere

joining the two data frames and concatenating the string is what i want to do.
